# Why Ghostscript (gswin32c.exe) prints only first page of my multipage PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, ghostscript

I am trying to print some multipage PDF files from NET 2.0 x86 console app using Ghostscipt (gswin32c.exe + gsdll32.dll). Everything is working just fine, but only first page of my PDF file is printed. Practicaly in our production environment almost any PDF document will contain multiple pages so I need to print all of them.

Here is the code I am using to send PDF-file to printer with GS:

```
using (PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog())
{
    dialog.AllowPrintToFile = false;
    dialog.AllowCurrentPage = false;
    dialog.AllowSomePages = false;
    dialog.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1;

    DialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
       info.Verb = "PDF silent print (gswin32c)";
       info.WorkingDirectory = tempDir;
       info.FileName = tempDir + @"\gswin32c.exe";
       info.CreateNoWindow = true;
       info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
       info.UseShellExecute = false;
       info.Arguments = String.Format(" -dPrinted -dBATCH -dNPAUSE -dNOSAFER -dNOPROMPT -dFIXEDMEDIA -dPDFFitPage -dNumCopies=1 -sDEVICE=mswinpr2 -sOutputFile=\"%printer%{0}\" \"{1}\"", new object[] { dialog.PrinterSettings.printerName, pdfFilename });

       using (Process p = Process.Start(info))
       {   
            p.WaitForExit(1 * 1000);

            if (!p.HasExited)
                p.Kill();
       }
}
```

Am I missing some GhostScript command line arguments?
Please help.

Comment: You have put -dNPAUSE instead of -dNOPAUSE. Ghostscript is almost certainly waiting for you to press a key to continue to page 2 and beyond. You really don't want to set -dFIXEDMEDIA, the mswinpr2 device interrogates the printer for thde taht. You can drop -dPDFFitPage for the same reason.

Comment: @KenS Thank you very much! Now it works like a charm. But I have to keep -dFIXEDMEDIA arguments to get my documents fitted to A4 paper size.

Comment: Just so you are aware; by setting FIXEDMEDIA wihthout setting a specific media size you are fixing the size to the default, and that can be different on different platforms. Also, if you try to print to different printers (with different sized media, eg Letter) I don't think you will get the correct result.